# assigning an ID to a domain object in a Grails integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-2.0

In my Grails 2.X app I have a `Foo` domain class. From an integration test, both of the following assertions pass:

```
def foo2 = new Foo()
foo2.id = 2L
assertEquals 2L, foo2.id // as expected

def foo = new Foo(id: 1L)
assertNull foo.id // not expected
```

In neither case do I make any attempt to persist the `Foo` instance. Why am I able to assign an id using the dot syntax, but not when I use the map constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `id` is not [bindable](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html) to domain class by default. It cannot be mentioned as a key value while defining a domain class until it is set as `bindable true` in domain constraints.

Comment: I don't doubt your explanation, but the description in the docs of properties that are not bindable doesn't seem to include domain class IDs:

"Properties which are not bindable by default are those related to transient fields, dynamically typed properties and static properties."

Comment: @Don As a matter of fact, `id` is a dynamically typed property if not specified explicitly. :)

Comment: Really? I thought it's a `Long` if not specified. Does this mean if you explictly define the id field with a type, it would then be bindable?

Comment: @Don [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5862087/) passes the test cases if use a string `id`.